# Empty accounts tab

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

How is it possible that there's no information in [accounts tab of this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635654/cygnusx1?tab=accounts)? Is it a bug? Or is it that I just don't have permission? How does it work?

Comment: There are [lots of accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) like that.  Does it only show for users with multiple accounts?

Comment: It the user doesn't have any accounts on any other site then this will be empty.

Comment: @ChrisF, that's surprising. I'd expect there to be at least the 'StackOverflow' site.

Comment: @TomasT. good point. Maybe there's the special case when there's only the one account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is now status-complete with the new profiles.

Comment: EDIT? I ___hope___ this is now status-obsolete?

Comment: **obsolete**? It seems it's **fixed** now!

Comment: I wanted to say **status-completed**.

Comment: Happy to hear that @TomasT.